# Is the pronunciation for the following sentences incorrect?

Tags: translation, transcription

In the following phrase I've transcribed from the audio the following sentence:

> dinner no sai ko no spice wa naaaan da?

In the subtitles it says,

> What's the best spice for dinner?

The next audio portion is:

> gok ke sho no kai na?

And the subtitles are:

> Sparkling conversation?

Is this correct? I've used a translation service and it is not the same translation as the subtitles. Also, is there a reason why someone would extend the phrase "naaaaaan" so long?

Link to [audio](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0C4qWwYamAQ)

Comment: Could you provide a link for the audio?

Comment: I've added the link to the audio. FYI I don't know how to read ビデオのリンクとかあります. I just want to know how to say it. It goes by too quickly and I do not hear all the sounds.

Comment: Sorry... I just meant to say "Do you have a link to the video?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are saying

> ディナーの[最高]{さいこう}のスパイスはなーんだ？
>   dinaa no saikou no supaisu wa naaanda?
>   [極上]{ごくじょう}の[会話]{かいわ}？
>   gokujou no kaiwa?
>   ご[名答]{めいとう}！
>   gomeitou!

Vowels are often lengthened to add emphasis (eg. こわい -> こわーい) or to sound casual/friendly (eg. ですね -> ですねー) and we also pronounce なんだ as なあーんだ at the end of a riddle, probably to sound playful or childlike.

Comment: could you tell me if the translation in English accurate? btw it's from a Lupin III episode

Comment: @1.21gigawatts The translation looks fine to me. (極上の literally means prime, superb, vintage, fancy...) "btw it's from a Lupin III episode" >> Haha yeah I can see that, it's Lupin and Fujiko